# Swift UI navigationLink from item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have problem with making this itemView to navigationLink. I need onTapGesture to open next list

https://github.com/reddogwow/test/blob/main/MainMenu

```
var objectView: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(objectname)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
        Image(objectphoto)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))

    }
    .frame(height: 200)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

Best edit will be where i can use Destination name from item (navMenu string)

---

I need something like this

```
        var body: some View {
//            NavigationView {
                let columns = Array(
                    repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: spacing),
                    count: numbersOfColumns)

                ScrollView {
                    HStack {
                    personView

                    petView
                    }
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing)   {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: item.navMenu) {
                                Text("")
                            } label: {
                                ItemView(item: item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea())
                .navigationTitle("")
//            }
        }
```

Where line NavigationLink(destination: HERE MUST BE STRING TO navMenu) But now im in cycle lot of fails

---

I have some menus called

Menu1.swift
Menu2.swift
Menu3.swift

I need open this menu after click on Grid menu.

But destination: Must be filled with name from item in code.

```
struct item: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let imgColor: Color
    let navMenu : String

}
```

```
        item(title: "Menu 1", image: "img1", imgColor: .orange, navMenu: "Menu1"),
```

I thing I have bad written buy maybe only small mistake

---

or maybe make it like this?

```
var navMenuDest = destination: + item.navMenu
```

this will be

```
NavigationLink(navMenuDest) {
```

in finale looks like

```
NavigationLink(destination: Menu1)
```

Comment: Can you show your `ContentView`'s code?

Comment: yes I can but sry. Formatting of post is pain :D

Comment: No problem, just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68662283/edit) your post and we can format it for you.

Comment: im first time here. But still  this: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

I make lot of added details and nothing

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `NavigationView` in the hierarchy to use `NavigationLink`. To make each `ItemView` navigate to a new view when tapped, we use `NavigationLink` as shown below.

Code:

```
struct MainMenu: View {
    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            let columns = Array(
                repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: spacing),
                count: numbersOfColumns)

            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                personView

                objectView
                }
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing)   {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Some destination view here...\n\nItem: \(String(describing: item))")
                        } label: {
                            ItemView(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea())
            .navigationTitle("Main Menu")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow. Thanks lot. I try make this for day. Everything end with bad coding.

Im back in coding after 8 years. Using google, YouTube and teaching meeting.

Thanks lot George for your help

Comment: @PetrKrist You're doing great, keep going!

Comment: @PetrKrist If this answer was useful, an 'accept answer'/upvote would be appreciated, and I'm sure by future readers too with the same problem :)

Comment: And when I need. Open next Menu1.swift ?

Comment: @PetrKrist I'm unsure what you mean

Comment: Description in next answer